# Does the Exporter plugin work in Extjs 6.0.1?

Tags: export-to-excel, extjs6, exporter

I saw a [thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301891-ExtJs-6.0-Grid-Excel-Export) that claims the Extjs 6 exporter plugin is broken.

What's the deal with this plugin? Please let me know your thoughts on the plugin because I want to use this plugin for exporting grid data to Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the export functionality in EXTJS 6 was not working. This is because if you use the responseHeader component to fetch the data to load into an XML, it would fail. The responseHeader was being returned as undefined.

This is fixed in 6.0.1.

I hope this is what you are looking for.